# Scoping C++ macros?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am working on a large C++ project. I have a bunch of macros that are used in a subset of the project, but I don't want to export them everywhere, to avoid contaminating unrelated code.

Right now, many of my files look like

```
#include <MyMacros.h> // defines MACRO_1, MACRO_2, ... MACRO_N

// bla
// bla

#undef MACRO_1
#undef MACRO_2
// ...
#undef MACRO_N
```

Of course, this is going to break the day I introduce `MACRO_N+1`.

Is there a better way to do somehow undefine all these macros at once?

Comment: You could not use macros - that would resolve the problem; or put all the code before the include of the macros that don't want them.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to undef several macros at once.

Comment: Why have you tagged this C? I would not use macros in the first place? C++ has better ways of doing things

Comment: So you define macros in C++ (some will answer "don't" right here). You define them in a header, which apparently gets included all over the place. But most includers do not want a significant part of the header. Only a (small) subset of includers need the macros. Why don't you have two headers, one with one without macros, or one without and one only with the macros?

Comment: @UKMonkey Unfortunately, in this case, I could do neither.

Comment: @Yunnosch Because I'm writing templates, which means that I need to put the implementation in the header, along with the macros.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate include file that undefines the macros in question and include that in your source files.

For example, in undefMacros.h:

```
#undef MACRO_1
#undef MACRO_2
// ...
#undef MACRO_N
```

Then in your source files:

```
#include <MyMacros.h> // defines MACRO_1, MACRO_2, ... MACRO_N

// bla
// bla

#include <undefMacros.h>
```

Then you only need to maintain the `#undef` statements in one place, in addition to where the macros are originally defined.

Comment: 2 places actually `<MyMacros.h>` and `<undefMacros.h>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 True.  Updated to clarify.

Comment: @Yoric Glad I could help.  Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found this useful.

Answer (score 1):

A variant on [dbush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49409544/2096401) would be to combine the definitions and clearing of the macros in one file:

**`MyMacros.h`**

```
#ifndef MACRO_1
#   define MACRO_1 ...
#   define MACRO_2 ...
...
#   define MACRO_N ...
//! Remember to add #undef if new macros are added
#else
#   undef MACRO_1
#   undef MACRO_2
...
#   undef MACRO_N
#endif
```

and then simply include this file at the top and bottom of where you use it:

```
#include "MyMacros.h"
...
...
...
#include "MyMacros.h"
```

Keeping everything in one file should make it easier to remember to add an `#undef` if you add a new macro.

Comment: @Yoric You could perhaps call the file `SetOrClearMacros.h` and/or call the "controlling" macro something like `MACROS_HAVE_BEEN_DEFINED`... yes, it is a little confusing, and if your set of macros is/were reasonably static, then dbush's answer is better, as it uses better-named (but separate) files. If the list of macros _is_ likely to change, then (to me) the advantage of having it all in one file begins to outweigh the confusion.